# Debug information in compiler explorer

Tags: assembly, x86, compiler-construction, compiler-explorer

What is the 'debug section' in compiler explorer?

```
.Letext0:
        .section        .debug_info,"",@progbits
.Ldebug_info0:
        .long   0x5d
        .value  0x4
        .long   .Ldebug_abbrev0
        .byte   0x8
        .uleb128 0x1
        .long   .LASF0
        .byte   0xc
        .long   .LASF1
        .long   .LASF2
        .quad   .Ltext0
        .quad   .Letext0-.Ltext0
        .long   .Ldebug_line0
        .uleb128 0x2
```

Is this something internal for compiler explorer to use, or what does this show exactly? I know I can get rid of this by filtering out **directives** and **unused labels**, but what is this section?

Here is an example: https://godbolt.org/z/oozxKj.

Comment: This is data for the debugger.

Comment: @Jester could you please elaborate a bit? Perhaps a few lines from the output and how that's used by the debugger.

Comment: The dwarf format is quite complicated. Along with the `.loc` and `.cfi` stuff this data enables the debugger to e.g. map source lines to instructions, know types of variables, do stack walks and such.

Comment: Google "dwarf debug info".  e.g. https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/systems/articles/au-dwarf-debug-format/.  This is the metadata that lets debuggers know which asm instructions go with each source line (which Compiler Explorer uses for colour highlighting), and where the value of each C variable is at any point in time, with I think some ability to track values through registers for `info vars` or `print my_var`.